# How to get message by last day in EWS?

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am writting some script in PowerShell and I want to get message from email.
I have a xml to get all message from EWS, but I want to get only message from yesterday.
Can anyone help me to do that?

```
$getInbox= @"
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FindItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
              xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
              Traversal="Shallow">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
     </ParentFolderIds>
     <QueryString>HasAttachments:true From:myEmail Kind:email</QueryString>
    </FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"@
```

Comment: do you mean exchange web services? or something else?

Comment: As Glen said, You can use relative date keywords in your search queries.
for example:'received:yesterday' and 'received:today'.
For more information, please see the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/querystring-querystringtype

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add received:yesterday to you querystring eg

`<QueryString>HasAttachments:true From:myEmail Kind:email received:yesterday</QueryString>`

Comment: Thank you ver much Glen. Is there possibility to search by yesterday and today? Some logic AND?
Example:  received:today and yesterday

Comment: use greater than eg received:>yesterday (or the actual date you want the result to be greater than)